# Opening webdav link with the correct program on client

Tags: java, applet, webdav

We have a browser based application which integrates a webdav server. We generate URLs to specific documents on our (webdav) servlet. (`https://server.com/webdav/path/to/file.doc`)

What we are looking for is a good way for our clients to open these links directly in the appropriate program. I.E. for a windows user, "`https://server.com/webdav/path/to/excelfile.xls`" should open in MS Excel, while the same link should open OOCalc on Linux.

So far, we've been using a small applet which maps has extensions, OS's, and programs and opens the program through `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(..)` . This approach works somewhat ok on Ms-Windows but is problematic on Linux and mac clients and is also quite inflexible.

Is there any better way of doing this?

Comment: The javascript found in my answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792960/editing-ms-office-documents-from-a-web-application-custom-webdav-implementation/6847137#6847137 may be helpful, along with the comment that went with it.  Basically, the client decides what to do with the file.  Unfortunately, I don't have any help for you on the Linux/Mac side of things.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this what tha java.awt.Desktop class was designed for?

I say "Designed for" because there are a lot of things that it doesn't do well or correctly, but it does work for some things.  Its missing the option for "open with", like the operating system has to prompt you for what you should open a document with if there's nothing registered for it.

It might interpret the url as a web url, open the browser, and then the browser might delegate to opening the file?  in that case you'd have to download the document to a temp file and then use desktop.open?

Comment: `Java.awt.Desktop` was no help unfortunately. this throws exceptions in the applet for not finding the 'file'. also i would doubt it would open the correct program, considering WebDav uses. HTTP(S). temp file also isnt an option because that would interfere with the save process
(we want our clients to edit these documents 'directly' on our servers.)

Answer (score 0):

If you set the MIME types of the files to the proper format, all browsers should be able to handle them. The user can then decide to take the default action for that type(open acrobat, word, excel, notepad) or pick a custom one.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately applet is the only solution for now. But in rare cases we use `"SharePoint.OpenDocuments"` and `'application/x-sharepoint'` plugins. You can compare with your solution [here](http://ajaxbrowser.com).

Answer (score 0):

It works great in Internet Explorer 10/11 these days.  But you will have to add a registry key in order to allow Office to open documents handed off from a browser as read/write.  The registry key is as follows:

> Office 2013:
>
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\Internet\OpenDocumentsReadWriteWhileBrowsing = 0x1 (DWORD)
>
> Office 2010:
>
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common\Internet\OpenDocumentsReadWriteWhileBrowsing = 0x1 (DWORD)

See this article for information about setting the key:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/06fedd90-4889-45ca-949d-60b76d74dd15/ms-word-open-document-readonly-with-WebDAV

Comment: intresting to hear, do you know if this is crossbrowser yet? (most of out users work on chrome these days)

Comment: @pvgoddijn Out of the box, no.  i.e. Firefox downloads to the local drive then hands it off, so office never even sees the WEBDAV url.  However, if you set up a local URI, similar to SharePoint Designer, it works with all browsers.

Comment: thanks for the info (however this wouldnt be an option because we cant allow these documents to be safed in a temp folder due to security issues). It might be usefull for others though