# Opening word document without office installed

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible to open a word document without ms office installed. I just have to open and diplay the word document in my webpage, I don't want to edit or modify. Is it possible, can anyone help me out here, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Please read this article: [Editing MS Office documents from a web application: custom WebDaV implementation or ...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792960/editing-ms-office-documents-from-a-web-application-custom-webdav-implementation).

What google returns to me when search:

http://www.textcontrol.com/en_US/sites/asp-dotnet-rich-text-box/?gclid=CIHcxpjU47kCFUMd3god818ACg

http://forums.asp.net/t/1356714.aspx

http://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/spire-office-for-net.html#.UkFTOxD4Ieg

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways to open word document without office installed

1.Using Google Docs

2.Download the free Open Office suite and you can open documents in Writer.

3.Download Microsoft Word Viewer 2007
This is a purely viewing only software offered for free by Microsoft which enables you to open Word documents but not edit them.

Comment: Can you guide me how to open word using word viewer in my application?